# DOM structure to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm working on "menu designer" - a tool to edit menu structure in the app's backend.
I have html code like this

```
<ul id="menu-designer-control">
    <li id="mi-2">
        <h3>Submenu header</h3>     
        <ul>
            <li id="mi-4"><h4>Hello world - article</h4></li>

            <li><!-- Drop here --></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="mi-1">
        <h3>Hello world - article</h3>      
        <ul>
            <li><!-- Drop here --></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

And I want to get array like this in PHP.

```
array(    
    2 /* top level item id */ => array( 4 /* children id */ ), 
    1 => array() /* or null or whatever */    
);
```

Could you please give me an advice how to do it? I've tried .sortable( 'serialize );, I've tried using each (on all li-s). Nothing with success - furthermore I'm not much familiar with javascript arrays :- / (So I'm pretty unsure how it should look and how to send it to the server… as a JSON object/string?).

Thank you a lot

(I'm using jQuery.)

Comment: Do you want solution only with JQuery, or non-JQuery solution would be enough?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function children(ul) {
  var lis = ul.children(), obj = {};
  lis.each(function(i, li) {
    var id = $(li).attr('id').substr(3);
    if ( id ) {
      obj[id] = children($('> ul', li));
    }
  });
  return obj;
}

var obj = children($('ul#menu-designer-control'));
console.log(obj);
```

The result would be objects in objects in objects etc. If only 2 lays of LI exist, the second layer objects will always be empty (that's alright). It's build to be recursive though: 3 layers, 4 layers etc, no problem.

**edit**
Tweaked it a little: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/xhLwF/

**edit**
Result in Chrome 10:

```
Object
  1: Object (empty)
  2: Object >
    4: Object (empty)
```

**edit**
Stringified JSON result:

```
{"1": {}, "2": {"4": {}}}
```

Comment: I don't know what that means... No need to check nodeTypes: jQuery queries only `HTMLElement`s.

Comment: <h3>Submenu header</h3> would be also parsed by your code. You must filter only li's or ul's

Comment: `.children()` queries only direct children. Direct children of an `UL` should only be `LI`, not `H3`. Try it on jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem. I wanted to write down edit with testing id and json stringify, but you already updated :o) Then in PHP I just used json_decode( $structure, true ); and now I have associative array. Thanks again.

Comment: There's a bug! I can't explain why, but when I use this in Opera, it doesn't care about order of items. I've solved it by dumb trying what it can be… and it is ".substr(3)". I removed it, added $id = (int)preg_replace( "~^mi-([0-9]+)~", "$1", $id ); (which is better anyway) to handler in PHP and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You must use objects to do this:

```
var dom = {
   "2":[4]
   ,
   "1":[]
};
```

I´m not sure if this is the answer to your question :)

Comment: I think that Ondrej wants to parse this code and get that array on output.